# Excel formulas for looking up cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am trying to look up (in cell B2) a specific string of text from a cell "F2" I want to look in the range of cells from "L2:Z2" if it finds a match in any of those cells (example M2), I would like to get that information into (cell B2.)

Can anyone assist me with this issue?

Comment: `INDEX(L:Z,2,MATCH(F2,L2:Z2,0))`

Comment: Hi Scott,  I tried that formula and got an #N/A. I can see the results within the range but I get no value returned.

Comment: You did not say it was a partial match `INDEX(L:Z,2,MATCH("*" & F2 & "*",L2:Z2,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(F2,$L$2:$Z$2,1,FALSE)),"",F2)
```

The formula looks whether the value in `F2` matches the value of any cell in the range from `L2:Z2` and, if that's the case, returns the value from `F2`. If there is no match the formula returns `""`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to return the matching value of the range from `L2:Z2`, you can put the following formula into cell `B2` and enter it with Control+Shift+Enter:

```
=INDEX(L2:Z2,1,MATCH(F2,LEFT(L2:Z2,LEN(F2)),0))
```

The formula looks for a match of the wanted color by comparing the value of `F2` to the first `x` characters of the cells in `L2:Z2`, where `x` is the number of characters of the color entered in `F2`.

Comment: The text from F2 WILL be located within range. example F2 contains "Red" the range from L2:Z2 could containt (L2 - Red Corvette) M2 - Blue Ford, N2 - Grey Tahoe ect...  Any time it sees F2 (Red) I need it to grab all of the text in the matching cell (Red Corvette). I hope this makes some kind of  sense.

Comment: I edited my post from above, the second formula should fit your needs.

Comment: @LMM9790 unless I am reading your formula wrong, you are only checking the start of the string.  WHICH MAY BE ALL THAT IS REQUIRED.  However what about the more general case of the search word in F2 is "red", and the entry in the data he is searching for has "Go Faster Red" or "Reddit" or "Dredge"?  Is It case sensitive?